# How do I downsample a signal using Octave?

Tags: matlab, octave

I have been trying to downsample a signal, but I'm not sure if I have the proper command? can you give me the proper command with a brief explanation?

Comment: Try the `resample` function from the `signal` package: https://octave.sourceforge.io/signal/function/resample.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on what you are trying to achieve, the [`downsample`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/signal/function/downsample.html) can be enough.

Example code:

```
pkg load signal % To download the signal package
x = cos(1:1000); % Create a signal
y = downsample(x, 2);
```

However, **it will not apply a low-pass filter** so it can introduce unwanted aliasing effects on your signal. Like the command `help downsample` says:

> For most signals you will want to use `decimate` instead since it prefilters the high frequency components of the signal and avoids aliasing effects.

---

Now if you want to downsample *and* apply the low-pass filter, you would like to use [`decimate`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/signal/function/decimate.html) but it only works for a downsampling with an integer factor, for example from 96kHz to 48kHz, you decimate by a factor 2. From `help decimate`

> Note that Q must be an **integer** for this rate change method.

Example code:

```
pkg load signal % To download the signal package
x = cos(1:1000); % Create a signal
y = decimate(x, 2);
```

---

Finally, if you want to  downsample by a rational number, for example by a factor of 2/3, from 96kHz to 64kHz, you will need [`resample`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/signal/function/resample.html) like it was suggested by other users.

```
pkg load signal % To download the signal package
x = cos(1:1000); % Create a signal
y = resample(x, 2, 3);
```

Note that you can still use `resample` to downsample by an integer factor, for example `y = resample(x, 1, 2);` but it slower that `decimate`.

Answer (score 0):

e.g.

```
y=resample(x,L,M);
```

> x is your signal
>
> L is increase sampling rate
>
> M is reduce sampling rate

Comment: do I have to declare L and M or is it just apart of the code?